# Getting certificate error when trying to run OSearch query from my laptop

Tags: security, certificate

I tried to debug OSearch results via VS and got the following certificate error.

[image]

```
WebException: HTTP return code Unauthorized. Description: Client cert is not received but is required for FD, [188.227.139.65]:58066 BN01APDC7F

WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

I have joined my team's security groups and do have access to CollectionsIndex and I am using VPN. It works for my other team members.
The issue is there when I run the built tool from command line too.

Some certificate seems to be missing and maybe the security team can help.